# Sorting-friendly language names with Intl.DisplayNames

Tags: javascript, localization, icu, cldr

Is there a way to use [Intl.DisplayNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DisplayNames) to get sorting-friendly language names where the base language comes first?

```js
const languageNames = new Intl.DisplayNames(['en'], { type: 'language' });
console.log(languageNames.of('en'));
console.log(languageNames.of('en-AU'));
console.log(languageNames.of('fr'));
console.log(languageNames.of('fr-CA'));
```

The above snippet returns:

```
English
Australian English
French
Canadian French
```

I'm looking for values formatted as documented in the CLDR [Language/Locale Name Patterns](https://cldr.unicode.org/translation/displaynames/languagelocale-name-patterns) page:

```
English
English (Australia)
French
French (Canada)
```

Some languages have `alt="menu"` variants [as of CLDR 36](https://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads/cldr-36), e.g. `Chinese, Cantonese` for `yue` (instead of the default `Cantonese`), but I'm not sure if these are exposed via JavaScript (and aren't defined for the languages in my example above, anyway).

I found a related ticket in the CLDR Jira: [ICU-21549: Fix the API to support language menus](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/ICU-21549)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `languageDisplay` option to `'standard'` produces the output you want:

```js
const languageNames = new Intl.DisplayNames(['en'], {
  type: 'language',
  languageDisplay: 'standard'
});
console.log(languageNames.of('en'));
console.log(languageNames.of('en-AU'));
console.log(languageNames.of('fr'));
console.log(languageNames.of('fr-CA'));
```

I don't know if it's possible to access the `menu` variants through this API.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this with the help of Intl.DisplayNames translations { type: "region" }

**code**

```
const languageNames = new Intl.DisplayNames(['en'], { type: 'language' });
const regionNames = new Intl.DisplayNames(["en"], { type: "region" });
const languagesObj = {};
const languages = [];

languagesObj['en'] = languageNames.of('en');
languagesObj['en-AU'] = languageNames.of('en-AU');
languagesObj['fr'] = languageNames.of('fr');
languagesObj['fr-CA'] = languageNames.of('fr-CA');

for (let lang in languagesObj) {
    if (lang.includes('-')) {
        const indexOfCountryLang = lang.indexOf('-');

        try {
            const language = languageNames.of(lang.slice(0, indexOfCountryLang)) ? languageNames.of(lang.slice(0, indexOfCountryLang)) : '';
            const region = regionNames.of(lang.slice(indexOfCountryLang + 1)) ? regionNames.of(lang.slice(indexOfCountryLang + 1)) : '';

            lang = `${language} (${region})`;
        } catch (error) {
            lang = languagesObj[lang];
        }
    } else {
        lang = languagesObj[lang];
    }

    languages.push(lang);
}

console.log(languages);
```

**output** `[ 'English', 'English (Australia)', 'French', 'French (Canada)' ]`

if any of instance not available in the languageNames.of() or regionNames.of() then it will keep default string